# SAX Parser support in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing, sax, apache-pig, saxparser

I am working on a UDF to process XML files on the Hadoop cluster. I am using PIG to load the XML files and then I use my UDF to flatten the structure of the XML data.

My current implementation is with DOM parser and I didn't have to include the DOM parser jars along with my udf jar. I am planning to shift this implementation from DOM parser to SAX parser.

Does the hadoop/pig framework provide those jars for SAX parsers out of the box or I need to have them included along with my udf jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I started working on the SAX Parser. And they just come right along with it.